# Multiple google forms with one trigger only (Google Apps Script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

This is a very simple question which I am really struggling to see if its possible or not.

I need to create multiple forms, however for each form created I also create a new trigger in which its limited for 20 triggers per user.
Sadly I really need to create at least 50 forms which would require 50 triggers and it is not possible.

Is there a way or a workaround to associate the same trigger for all the forms?
Has anyone found a solution for this? I can't seem to find any option to attach an existing trigger also

Comment: you can put several of the forms into one project (ie container).  Within a container when you get a form submit trigger you can use e.range.getSheet() to determine the linked sheet which corresponds to a form.  So you can use an object to determine which form your trigger is for by using sheet names as keys and form names as values.

Answer (score 0):

#### Appending all form data to unique no linked sheets for each form

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const osn = {'Form Response 1':'Sheet1','Form Response 2':'Sheet2','Form Response 3':'Sheet3'};
  e.source.getSheetByName(osn[sh.getName()]).appendRow(e.values);//appending data to sheet for each form
}
```